# Using COPY on dockerfile for apache build

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to build a small dockefile for apache just for testing.

```
FROM httpd:2.2.31

RUN mkdir -p /opt/mw/apache-test/logs

ADD ./httpd-custom.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY /opt/mw/apache-2.2.31-instance1/htdocs/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

But for some reason I getting an error with the COPY.
Also, I tried to use ADD.
This is the error I got:

```
Step 4 : COPY /opt/mw/apache-2.2.31-instance1/htdocs/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
lstat opt/mw/apache-2.2.31-instance1/htdocs/: no such file or directory
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the directory /opt/mw/apache-2.2.31-instance1/htdocs/ exist on your host ?

Comment: And more importantly, does that directory exist in the path you're passing as the context for building your image? Also, try not to mix ADD and COPY, Docker recommends using COPY. And remove the trailing slash on the source folder

Comment: For the first question, yes the directory exist. Its the one I've been using for testing.
For the second question. I guess it exists, I'm using the Apache image.
https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understand that you do not want to mount the volumes and instead wanted have those files part of the image so that it can be shared. At least assuming this.

As per the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

> COPY obeys the following rules:
>    - The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.
>    - If  is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, including filesystem metadata.

You might got the the problem by now. In your `Dockerfile` i.e., `COPY` statement is the problem since it is referring to absolute path which is not following the 1st rule from the above. So, `htdocs` should be available in the local directory from which you execute the `docker build` command.

The following changes need to made before building the image:

- Hope you might have already created a directory(which you are building image ) and this directory contains `Dockerfile`, `httpd-custom.conf` files.
- Now, go into above directory and copy `/opt/mw/apache-2.2.31-instance1/htdocs` to current directory. So, that `htdocs` directory can be now part of context ( as mentioned in the docs) while building the image.
- Change the contents of `Dockerfile` to the following(mainly COPY command):

```
FROM httpd:2.2.31

RUN mkdir -p /opt/mw/apache-test/logs

ADD ./httpd-custom.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY htdocs /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

Now you should be able to build it successfully.

For just demo, used a light weight `busybox` and create a directory in the same context (to simulate your case) and it does as you see below:

```
$ more Dockerfile 
FROM busybox
COPY data_folder  /opt/data_folder
CMD ["ls", "/opt/data_folder"]

$ ls
data_folder  Dockerfile
$ ls data_folder/
test.txt
```

**Build Image:**

```
$ sudo docker build  -t dirtest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.584 kB
Step 1 : FROM busybox
 ---> e02e811dd08f
Step 2 : COPY data_folder /opt/data_folder
 ---> b6b1a9555825
Removing intermediate container b682e0467803
Step 3 : CMD ls /opt/data_folder
 ---> Running in 3b05f08ceafc
 ---> b73190fc1fd9
Removing intermediate container 3b05f08ceafc
Successfully built b73190fc1fd9
```

**Running above Image in a Container** which shows directory 'data_folder' is copied and showing its contents. In your case, it is `htdocs`

```
$ sudo docker run -it --rm --name testdirtest dirtest
test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Files you ADD or COPY into a docker image need to exist within your build directory. If you run `docker build -t myimage .`, then `.` is your build directory. The `docker build` packages up all files in the build directory excluding anything listed in .dockerignore, uploads them to the docker host you are connected to (it may be a remote server).

If you simply want the htdocs to be accessible inside of the running container, then I'd bind the host directory into the container as a volume during `docker run`. For example, `docker run -v /opt/mw/apache-2.2.31-instance1/htdocs/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/:ro yourimagename`. In fact, if your Dockerfile only has those lines, you can completely skip the build and run:

```
docker run \
  -v `pwd`/httpd-custom.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:ro \
  -v /opt/mw/apache-2.2.31-instance1/htdocs/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/:ro \
  -v `pwd`/logs:/opt/mw/apache-test/logs \
  httpd:2.2.31
```

Note that if you're using docker for windows or Mac, these host directories need to be in a shared directory with the Docker VM, which by default includes the /Users folder.

Comment: Actually that worked, but I wanted to build an image using the dockerfile for testing

Comment: To build the image, then simply follow the directions in my first paragraph, moving /opt/mw/... into your build directory.